# How to add fields to a request?

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a login page. Upon submission if 'webmail' is selected, the request
should be redirected to the webmail server, with the credentials submitted but
under different keys. Here's what I'm trying now:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    if form.destination.data == 'webmail':
        form.rc_user.data = form.email.data
        form.rc_password.data = form.password.data
        return redirect('https://example.com/webmail/', code=307)
```

This almost works: the `POST` is redirected to webmail. However the values
submitted are the default values, not the assigned values.

I have some more issues though:

- the keys should be `_user` and `_pass`, but Flask seems to blow up with
  leading-underscore field names.
- I do not want to add these fields to the original class. I want to subclass 
  upon submission, somewhat as follows:

  ```
  if form.validate_on_submit():
      if form.destination.data == 'webmail':
          class WebmailLoginForm(LoginForm):
              rc_user = EmailField('user', default=form.email.data)
          form = WebmailLoginForm(request.form)
          return redirect('https://example.com/webmail/', code=307)
  ```

  When I do this, the added fields show up as `UnboundField` and are not 
  submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When issuing a *redirect*, the browser is simply told to resubmit to another server. I.e. it's too late for the server to influence the request.

So either: start a new request, or use javascript to change the submit target.

Thanks to my colleague Johan for kickstarting my brain.